# How to transform a Dofile to PDF

Tags: pdf, stata

I have a dofile and I want to convert to a PDF. My idea is that even people that do not have access to Stata can see the codes that I wrote.

I tried this

```
translate TEST_FE (1).do pdffile, translator(txt2pdf)
```

and found this: varlist not allowed

`db markdoc` is also not working

Comment: As a do-file is pure text, you don't need to translate it to any other file format to share it with people. The only small problem is that other people may need to insist to their software that anything with a `.do` extension is text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `translate "TEST_FE (1).do" "pdffile.pdf", translator(txt2pdf)`

Your do-file has a space in the name. Then it needs to be in `" "` quotes as there otherwise is no way for Stata to know where the file name ends.

In general, try to avoid spaces in technical file names such as scripts and data files. As well as special characters part from `_` and `-`. That will make it less likely for you to run in to odd errors.